# Negation of sequential definition of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

The sequential definition of a compact set is given as:

> A set $K \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ is compact if every sequence in $K$ has
>   a sub-sequence that converges to a limit that is also in $K$.

In trying to negate the above definition, am I correct in saying that a set $K \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ is *not* compact if there exists a sequence in $K$ such that all subsequences are 1) divergent or 2) converges to a limit that is not in $K$?

Comment: A set $A$ in a metric space is not compact if  there exists a sequence in $A$ which does not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: A set $K$ in a general topological space is indeed not sequentially compact if you can show that there exists a sequence which does not have a convergent subsequence in $K$.

Comment: So in $\mathbf{R}$, my negation above is correct?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ this indeed also implies that your set is not compact. This follows from the equivalence of compactness and sequential compactness in metric spaces.